# How do I drop or select specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data and would like to drop any rows where the LSOA code doesn't start with 'E01' or alternatively create a new data frame with only the rows that start with 'E01'. Can anyone help with this?

```
    LSOA code   0
0   E01000001   359
1   E01000002   336
2   E01000003   68
3   E01000005   748
4   E01000006   110
... ... ...
6228    W01001867   1
6229    W01001870   3
6230    W01001913   1
6231    W01001938   1
6232    W01001941   1
```

Comment: `df[df['LSOA code'].str.startswith('E01')]`?

Comment: `df[df['LSOA code'].str.match('E01', na=False)]` also works

Answer (score 1):

[Following the Pandas documentation:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)

`df_new = df[df['LSOA code'].str.startswith('E01')]`

This returns a new dataframe `df_new` which only contains rows that start with `E01`.

If you want to have a df that does not have those rows, do the opposite:

`df_new = df[~df['LSOA code'].str.startswith('E01')]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, all sorted!